# Is my CPU overheating?

Tags: temperature, overheating

I was advised to use 'System Stability Test' to check up on My CPU. But I'm not sure I understand the results so far! The program says the CPU is overheating but the average temps seem to be okay? I made a comparison with 'HWMonitor' Should I be worried with the results?
The CPU I'm using is i9-10900KF, air cooled with CoolerMaster MA410m.

System Stability Test and HWMonitor Test results:

[image: System Stability Test and HWMonitor Test results]

Comment: Is your cpu throttling itself? If the answer to that question is no then your laain’t overheating

Comment: Those temperatures are during stress test, right? What temperatures do you see when the CPU is completely idle?

Comment: Yes, those temps are during the stress test. Usually, when idle, the temps hover in the 40s. What do you mean 'throttling itself'?

Comment: Deliberately slowing itself down (in order to stay below a programmed temperature limit, in this case)

Comment: I'm not sure! How can I tell? While gaming I can see (using MSI Afterburner) that CPU temps sometimes reach the 90s but I don't feel a drop in performance.

Comment: @MuhammadDiab - “drop in performance” but is it thermally throttling? The temperatures you describe are not necessarily high. A quality air cooler should be more then enough to cool the cpu.  If you have performance problems then that might indicate poor thermal paste application.  You have not provided the values for the clock so we cannot tell if your cpu is being throttled

Comment: Check your mainboard BIOS, a lot of manufacturer allow Intel CPUs set the "long/short duration power limit" to unlimited or a very high value. In such cases the CPU temperature can also massively increase. It is recommended to correct those values to meaningful values (e.g. short power limit 250W, long power limit 125 Watt).

Answer (score 0):

*Google-based answer, I'm not a hardware expert*

The absolute maximum temperature allowed in [the datasheet](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/199331/intel-core-i9-10900kf-processor-20m-cache-up-to-5-30-ghz.html) of i9-10900KF (beyond which the CPU could potentially damage itself) is 100°C. So in normal operation it is supposed to stay well below that temperature (probably below ~90°C or so).

According to the screenshot, your CPU reached the maximum 100°C within *the first minute* of the test. That seems kind of bad and you should be worried.

> The program says the CPU is overheating but the average temps seem to be okay?

It seems that this is only because after reaching the maximum allowed temp, the CPU automatically reduced (i.e. throttled) its speed to keep its temperature in control. Now it's no longer overheating at ~70°C, but that doesn't mean everything is fine – it shouldn't have *needed* to do this, i.e. it shouldn't have reached 90–100°C in the first place.

(I.e. if you keep having fires but the fire suppression system quickly deals with them, you aren't going to say "but there's no fire *now* so everything is fine", are you.)